# Не могу спарсить dotabuff (python)

Tags: python, html, парсер

При изучении парсинга у меня появилась проблема. Я не могу спарсить полностью html дотабафа полностью.
Парсяться только:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   

<html>
<head>
<title>429 Restricted</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error 429 Restricted</h1>
<p>Restricted</p>
<h3>Guru Mediation:</h3>
<p>Details: cache-hhn4028-HHN 1645208045 2173311123</p> 
<hr/>
<p>Varnish cache server</p>
</body>
</html>
```

А не данные body, div и так далее

При всём этом у меня код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get("https://uk.dotabuff.com/players/70388657/matches")
html = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(html)
```

Comment: Закосить под браузер, пропишите headers.

Comment: Я новичок в этом, можете подсказать как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0'}
r = requests.get("https://uk.dotabuff.com/players/70388657/matches", headers=header)
```

Comment: Я получил <Response [200]> error

Comment: У меня все работает. Как альтернативу можете прописать другой User-Agent.  Найдете на просторах интернета

Comment: Закос под хром 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'

Comment: Это работает! но значений внутри, таких как процент побед я не увидел, как это решить?

Comment: Если вы про 53.04%? То в html они присутвуют.

Comment: Я использую тот код, который указал выше и не могу получить мои значения. Может быть мой код отличаеться от вашего?

Comment: код тот же. Только проценты я искал ручками, чтобы убедиться что они существуют в html. А как вы ишете мне не дано знать.

Comment: Так в том прикол, что я через поиск блокнота не нашёл. И глазами смотрел, тоже не нашёл. В чём же тогда проблема?

Comment: Сравните html который выдает код с исходной страницой в браузере.

Comment: Оно кидает мне только head часть, а не body. Как мне получить body?

Comment: что за head, что за body? Не какой конкретики. Это для вас понятно, но не мне.